# How to use Harmony activity to change mode on SmartThings?

Tags: samsung-smartthings, logitech-harmony

I have an activity on Harmony (watch tv) that works fine. Turns on the tv, tunes in a channel, turns on the LED strip behind the tv.

The problem is that the mode on SmartThings doesn’t change. So if the mode is, for example, away, it will remain away and since I have a SmartApp configured to turn off the lights if no motion after 1 minute in away mode, the LED strip turns off 1 minute after the activity is triggered.

I have tried the virtual switch thing, but I couldn’t get it to work.

Can anyone shed a light?

Comment: What didn't work with the virtual switch?